# Flutter- Issue when passing the value and return it's value

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I have class CTAButton which extend BaseStatelessWidget<HomeBloc, IGeneralState>,from this class I use a variable called isLoading which passing to the CTAButton class to make the CircularProgressIndicator shown. When I click on CTAButton it called an event from BaseStatelessWidget the event at first be as Loading then Success, d**uring the loading time I need to let the isLoading = true to let the CircularProgressIndicator shown**, and after the event become Success it move to next page and return the isLoading = flase and CircularProgressIndicator disappere, **but always I recieve the value of isLoading =flase.**

Here some of the classes I used :

```
class BaseStatelessWidget<B extends Bloc<dynamic, T>, T> extends StatelessWidget {
  bool isLoading = false;
@override
  BlocProvider<B> build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider.value(
      value: onCreate(context),
      child: WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () {
          dispose();

          return Future.value(true);
        },
        child: _buildBaseView(context),
      ),
    );
  }
// continue the code ...etc

// when press the button an call the event.
  @protected
  void _onListener(context, state) {
    // printLog('[BaseState] onListener $state');
    if (state is Loading) {
      isLoading = true;
      onLoadingListener(state);
    } else if (state is Success) {
      isLoading = false;
      onSuccessListener(state);
    } else if (state is Exception) {
      isLoading = false;
      onExceptionListener(state);
    }
  }
}
```

```
class CTAButton extends BaseStatelessWidget<HomeBloc<HomeState>, IGeneralState<HomeState>> {
 return Center(
      child: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: PhysicalModel(
          elevation: 4,
          shadowColor: Colors.black,
          color: mainColor,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
          child: SizedBox(
              height: 328,
              width: 50,
              child: ElevatedButton(
                  elevation: MaterialStateProperty.all<double>(0),
                  shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                    RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(radius),
                      side: border,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                child: setUpButtonChild(context),
                onPressed: onPressed == null
                    ? null
                    : () {
                        if (onPressed != null) {
                          onPressed!();
                        }
                      },
              )),
return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        if (isLoading)
          SizedBox(
            height: indicator,
            width: indicator,
            child: const Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                value: null,
                valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        if (isLoading) const SizedBox(width: 10),
        text
      ],
    );
}
```

Here using the CTAButton in class and called it on somewhere in the code:

```
class HomeScreen extends BaseStatelessWidget<HomeBloc<HomeState>, IGeneralState<HomeState>> {
 //code 
// Details it's a widget that containe the CTAButton.
  return Details(
                        key: Key("DetailsStart"),
                        onTap: () {
                         // Event call the method of _onListener from BaseStatelessWidget
                          broadcastEvent(
                            ArriveToLocationEvent(
                              //code of event some args
                            ),
                          );
                          broadcastEvent(RefreshMarkersEvent(pageBloc.homeState.homeMarkers));
                        },
                      );
}
```

I passing isLoading to show CircularProgressIndicator but always I recieved isLoading =show, and I want to take it's value in correct way to show CircularProgressIndicator when click the CTAButton